# unable to measure temp value using temprature sensor in arduiono kit

Tags: sensors, arduino-uno

unable to measure temperature from temperature sensor in arduino ,
its giving wrong temp = Temprature =499.51 * c. im connected tempreture sensor to arduino uno kit . i need the temp value like 35

```
int val;
int tempPin = 1;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop()
{
  val = analogRead(tempPin);
  float mv = ( val / 1024.0) * 5000;
  float cel = mv / 10;
  float farh = (cel * 9) / 5 + 32;

  Serial.print("TEMPRATURE = ");
  Serial.print(cel);
  Serial.print("*C");
  Serial.println();
  delay(1000);

  /* uncomment this to get temperature in farenhite
    Serial.print("TEMPRATURE = ");
    Serial.print(farh);
    Serial.print("*F");
    Serial.println();


  */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what temperature sensor you are using. From your code, it would seem that you use an analog sensor. If so, you should

```
a) check the data sheet of the sensor and adjust your code accordingly
OR
b) calibrate your system by taking readings of known temperatures and adjusting your code accordingly.
```

With the info you give, it is difficult to be more specific.